# Is it possible to isolate the interaction component of a GBM?

Tags: r, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, random-forest, boosting

In a GLM we can specify the interaction component. I have an optimization program that has the linear systematic components of a GLM and when a variable changes it gets multiplied by the interaction component and then along with the rest of the covariates get transformed into a probability. This means we do not need to run a predict() function to get the new probability after the change.

Now, I have a Gradient boosted regression model, which is just many, many trees trained optimally and averaged to produce a node values, and then transformed into the probability response. I want to make it compatible with the optimization program but I am not aware of a way to isolate the interaction component in the same way.

The best idea I have is to do this process:

Make two predictions at varying levels of the variable I want to interact with, take the log odds of the GBM predictions, find the slope, and say that this is the interaction coefficient, similar to a GLM.

Is this the best way to do it?